# specify time of day for org-resolve-clocks, not number of minutes

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I can use [`org-resolve-clocks`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Resolving-idle-time.html) if I've been away from a task but kept the clock for the task running -- but when I do that and select `K` ("keeps however many minutes you request and then immediately clock out of that task."), I have to specify a number of *minutes*.

Instead, I want to specify a time, since usually that's what I remember ("my coworker stopped to ask a question at 10:45"). I'd like a way to get the `K` functionality, but instead of doing the math to figure out a number of minutes, I want to just type in a time of day.

What would I need to do for that?

Comment: This would make a very nice request-for-enhancement IMO (if it does not exist already of course). You might want to propose it on the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html) if you get no answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's no way for org to do this right now. But I've sent a patch to the org-mode mailing list; the change to `org-clock.el` is quite simple:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2020-01/msg00175.html

Comment: This is now available as of this commit: https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/57841b5264 - thanks!